# why my College computer's settings and data are restored back after a shut down?

Tags: operating-system

My Institution Desktops' when they are shut down are being restored to some default settings and data. I have uninstalled some applications and installed some other one's in my Institute desktop in my Lab before a break. And after the break when I turned it on, all my settings are lost, and default settings are restored. The applications I installed got vanished and the applications which I uninstalled are back. I didn't understand that..

I try to find some answers to this in other websites, but I didn't get the appropriate one. I just want to know the procedure of that desktop settings or software's used.

Comment: The next time you use your institution's computer, try pressing `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+F6`. If a Deep Freeze console password prompt appears, that means your institution set up Faronics Deep Freeze on that computer (as Ove said). I know this because my university uses it. AFAIK, Deep Freeze works at a lower level than the operating system, and it resets the computer's disk to whatever state the administrator configured, on each boot. However, it could be any other software too, or the Deep Freeze console could be hidden or bound to another hotkey.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely they bought some software that does this for them.

Here is the first one I found
https://www.faronics.com/en-uk/products/deep-freeze/enterprise
and here are some alternatives
https://alternativeto.net/software/deep-freeze/